# Memory Leak on ImageIcon in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, memory, imageicon

How to solved Memory Leak on ImageIcon in Java?

```
ImageIcon icon_requirements    = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/icon_error.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(15, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak? Is the code throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: Yes i Know. it always  throwing an OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Yes i Know. it always  throwing an OutOfMemoryError

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).